# VBA/Excel - Copy worksheet to another workbook (Replace existing values)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values from one sheet, into another workbooks sheet. However I can't get Excel to actually paste the values to the other workbook.

This my code.

```
Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim src As Workbook ' SOURCE
    Dim currentWbk As Workbook ' WORKBOOK TO PASTE VALUES TO

    Set src = openDataFile
    Set currentWbk = ActiveWorkbook

     'Clear existing data
     currentWbk.Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents

     src.Sheets(1).Copy After:=currentWbk.Sheets(1)

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
     src.Close False  ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
     Set src = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And below is the function `openDataFile` which is used to get the source workbok (File Dialog):

```
Function openDataFile() As Workbook
'
Dim wb            As Workbook
Dim filename      As String
Dim fd            As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.Title = "Select the file to extract data"

' Optional properties: Add filters
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*" ' show Excel file extensions only

' means success opening the FileDialog
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
End If

' error handling if the user didn't select any file
If filename = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Excel file was selected !", vbExclamation, "Warning"
    End
End If

Set openDataFile = Workbooks.Open(filename)

End Function
```

When I try to run my Sub, it opens the `src` file and just stops there. No values are copied and pasted to my `currentWbk`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you open a workbook it becomes the active one so this is the same as the source workbook `Set currentWbk = ActiveWorkbook`. You probably need `ThisWorkbook`. (Not that there is any pasting in your code anyway.)

Comment: You're not actually copy/pasting data. Your code is copying an entire worksheet into the destination workbook. So performing the `.ClearContents` means you'll always have a blank worksheet, then a new worksheet copied behind that one. This is in addition to the issue pointed out by @SJR above.

Comment: Thanks - changing it to `ThisWorkbook` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my sub will help u

```
Public Sub CopyData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = GetFile("Get book") 'U need use your  openDataFile  here
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Data")'enter your name of ws

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    wsSource.Cells.Copy ws.Cells
    wb.Close False

End Sub
```